# How to fix a compile syntax error in the first line of my code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use some basic code in order to lock all of my cells with formulas with a password.

I have tried looking at various solutions to this issue, but none seem to specifically address the general issue and are rather concerned with very specific issues. The highlighted line is excel is the very first line shown.

```
Sub ProtectFormulas()
    Dim strPassword As String
    With ActiveSheet
    .Unprotect
    .Cells.Locked = False
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
    .Protect AllowDeletingRows:=True
    strPassword = InputBox(“Please enter the password (optional)”
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strPassword
End With
End Sub
```

I expect a dialogue box to pop up so I can enter a password to lock all formulas, but I get an immediate error.

Comment: To be clear, you're getting an error on `Dim strPassword As String`? What error are you getting?

Comment: `strPassword = InputBox(“Please enter the password (optional)”` doesn't have a closing parenthesis for the input box.

Comment: Also, make sure you're NOT using opening/closing double quotes on the string. Just use the simple double quote: `strPassword = InputBox("Please enter the password (optional)"`

Comment: (@PeterT - don't forget the closing parenthesis.)  Also a note to OP - if it's optional, I *think* if the user puts "Cancel" or just hits "Enter" on the InputBox, wouldn't it technically get a password, it would just be an empty space?  May want to add a control of like, `If strPassword <> "" Then ActiveSheet.Protect Password=strPassword`.

Comment: @BruceWayne an empty string is the only password I ever use to protect worksheets =) ...anything else is thwarted in a few seconds anyway, if it's not just plain hard-coded right there in the VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

As I run your code I saw that there is no problem in code where there is a formula containing cell in your activesheet. Make sure that there is at least one cell that contains a formula.
in order to skip this error use bellow code in first line of your sub so you will never face error if your activesheet does not have any formula containing cell.
        `on error resume next`

Comment: I highly suggest not adding the resume next to the top line. It will hide errors and likely lead to more headaches than it "solves".